# C++: Fast Concatenation of Irregularly Sized Binary Codewords

Tags: c++, memory, binary, concatenation

I need to stream serial data out of a hardware SPI module. This SPI module accepts 16-bit words and transmits them MSB first.

To feed the SPI module, I have prepared an array of 16-bit integers.

Here's the tricky part: the data that I'm going to be streaming out of the SPI module is not constructed from 16-bit wide words. Instead, 588 bits in 68 codewords need to be output as follows:

The first word, codeIndex=0, is 24 bits wide
Every other word (codeIndex=x for all odd numbers x) is 3 bits wide
All remaining codewords (codeIndex=x for all nonzero even numbers) is 14 bits wide

The SPI interface must stream out all of these code words in sequence with no added or missing bits. That means that the first 16-bit word that I send to the SPI interface needs to be the most significant 16 bits of the 24 bit codeIndex=0, and the next 16-bit word would be the remaining eight bits of codeIndex=0 followed by all three bits of codeIndex=1 followed by the most significant five bits of codeIndex=2, and the next 16-bit word sent to the SPI interface would finish off codeIndex=2 and so on.

I've come up with an approach for this that makes heavy use of binary OR operators and bitwise shifts, but it seems like there should be a faster way to do this by manipulating pointers or something.

My approach makes use of a lookup table. Each row of the lookup table defines a 16-bit word in terms of how many irregular codewords appear in it, which codewords appear in it, and the bitwise offsets that must be applied to those codewords before their ones are OR'd into the 16-bit word. Because 588 bits fills exactly 36.75 16-bit words, I've made this table four iterations long to perfectly fill 147 16-bit words. You can see in the code below that I have unrolled some loops in the program to try and speed it up further.

```
void fillBuffer(volatile uint16_t *buf) {
  #define THIS_CODE_INDEX *codeIndex
  #define THIS_CODE_OFFSET *codeOffset

  //is the codeword merging bits? 
  #define CODE_SELECT_ITERATION \
  if ( (THIS_CODE_INDEX & 1) == 1) { \
    codeWord = mBitPattern[frame.mBits[(THIS_CODE_INDEX-1)>>1]];\
  }\
  /*is it a normal data word?*/\
  else if (THIS_CODE_INDEX > 2) {\
    codeWord = efmCode[frame.data[(THIS_CODE_INDEX>>1)-1]];\
  }\
  /*is it the sync word?*/\
  else if (THIS_CODE_INDEX == 0) {\
    codeWord = 0b100000000001000000000010;\
  }\
  /*it must be the control bits*/\
  else {\
    if (frameIndex >= 2) { /*if this is the third frame or beyond,*/\
      codeWord = efmCode[frame.data[(THIS_CODE_INDEX>>1)-1]];\
    }\
    else if (frameIndex==0) {  /*if it's the first frame,*/\
      codeWord = 0b00100000000001; /*use s1*/\
    }\
    else {  /*if it's the second frame,*/\
      codeWord = 0b00000000010010; /*use s2*/\
    }\
  }\

  #define CODE_OUTPUT_ITERATION(n) \
  if (THIS_CODE_OFFSET < 0) buf[n] |= ((uint16_t) (codeWord >> (THIS_CODE_OFFSET*-1)));\
  buf[n] |= ((uint16_t) (codeWord << THIS_CODE_OFFSET));

  #define THIS_CODE_COUNT wordCount

  #define FRAME_ITERATION(n) \
    int8_t wordCount = decompTable[n][0];\
    buf[n]=0;\
    \
    /*for each codeword that makes up this 16 bit frame:*/\
    codeIndex = &decompTable[n][1];\
    codeOffset = &decompTable[n][2];\
    \
    {\
      CODE_SELECT_ITERATION\
      CODE_OUTPUT_ITERATION(n)\
      \
      if (THIS_CODE_COUNT > 1){\
        codeIndex+=2;\
        codeOffset+=2;\
        \
        CODE_SELECT_ITERATION\
        CODE_OUTPUT_ITERATION(n)\
        \
        if (THIS_CODE_COUNT > 2) {\
          codeIndex+=2;\
          codeOffset+=2;\
          \
          CODE_SELECT_ITERATION\
          CODE_OUTPUT_ITERATION(n)\
        }\
      }\
    }\



  uint32_t codeWord;

  const int8_t *codeIndex = &decompTable[0][1];
  const int8_t *codeOffset = &decompTable[0][2];


  for (uint8_t i =  0; i <  37; i++) {
    FRAME_ITERATION(i)
  }

  frameIndex++;

  for (uint8_t i = 37; i <  74; i++) {
    FRAME_ITERATION(i)
  }

  frameIndex++;

  for (uint8_t i = 74; i < 111; i++) {
    FRAME_ITERATION(i)
  }

  frameIndex++;

  for (uint8_t i =111; i < 147; i++) {
    FRAME_ITERATION(i)
  }
}
```

I hope that's not too messy.

It seems like this type of problem would have come up somewhere before I got to it though. Is there a faster way to perform this calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking about runtime speed (not programming speed). I assume this is a 16-bit controller/processor?

We have 4*68 code words from memory which we have to convert into the 147 16-bit words for SPI.

The fastest approach seems to be

- read codeword
- opt.: shift codeword left, OR
- opt.: write result, increase pointer, SET 0
- opt.: shift codeword right, SET

In comparison to your current solution, as you already unrolled the loops, I wouldn't read the decompTables from memory, but hardcode them into the program. You could create one macro that adds one codeword and give all the relevant values and actions as macro names and parameters. Then call this macro 272 times. E.g.:

```
#define ADDCW16_SHL(shl) \
   cw = *ptr_cw; \
   ptr_cw++; \
   temp |= cw << shl;

#define ADDCW16_WRITE() \
   cw = *ptr_cw; \
   ptr_cw++; \
   temp |= cw;
   *ptr_spi = temp; \
   ptr_spi++; \
   temp = 0;

#define ADDCW16_SHR_WRITE_SHL(shr, shl) \
   cw = *ptr_cw; \
   ptr_cw++; \
   temp |= cw >> shr;
   *ptr_spi = temp; \
   ptr_spi++; \
   temp = cw << shl;

uint16_t cw;
uint16_t temp;
ptr_cw = &codewords[0];
ptr_spi = &spibuf[0];

ADDCW16_WRITE() // first 16 bits of 24 bit codeword 1
ADDCW16_SHL(8) // second 8 bits of 24 bit codeword 1
ADDCW16_SHL(5) // 3 bit codeword 2
ADDCW16_SHR_WRITE_SHL(9, 7) // 14 bit codeword 3 (split 5 bit / 9 bit)
ADDCW16_SHL(4) // 3 bit codeword 4
ADDCW16_SHR_WRITE_SHL(10, 6) // 14 bit codeword 5 (split 4 bit / 10 bit)
// ...
```

You would split the first 24 bit codeword into two codewords (two calls to ADDCW16). The other codewords have exactly one macro call per codeword. The ADDCW16 calls could be generated by a small computer routine.

Alternatively you could use the boost headers library (it ist headers only and you would just use that small part of boost). It provides loops and arithmetic operations within the preprocessor (by using the existing preprocessor and very clever symbol manipulation).

Comment: It took me most of the day to understand and implement your answer. After writing a python script to read my table and generate the proper order of macros, resulting algorithm executes a little more than twice as quickly as the function I posted as part of this question. Thank you very much for a clever trick.

Comment: I am glad that it had this speed-up and that it worked. Depending on the underlying machine, you can further try to tweak the code (but most probably the compiler with optimization activated could do it): 1. temp=0 in ADDCW16_WRITE can be removed, if the following macro uses temp= instead of temp|= 2. if the memory architecture is 32 bits or 64 bits and the CPU is fast, you can read/write a larger chunk (but compiler should do it) 3. if the CPU has more than 16 bits you could shift inside larger registers, perhaps you could directly write the upper 16 bits of the register as soon as filled